# ionic 4 - how to call component method and vice-versa

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've added my component in the page this way:

```
<app-modal-product></app-modal-product>
```

So, how can I call methods inside my component, and also how to call parent page methods from the component?

Comment: For what purpose do you wish to call the methods in another component? Do you want to pass some data to it?

Comment: @MichaelD exactly

Comment: Then one quick Angular way of doing it would be to create a shared singleton service between the components and define the data and it's related methods in it. That way there is only one copy of the data and both components have access to it.

Comment: its a good workaround, thanks

Comment: It wouldn't be a workaround. It is one of the documented ways to share data and methods between components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add reference variable to your component.

   `<app-modal-product #modalproduct></app-modal-product>`
2. Get component reference in the parent component.

   `@ViewChild('modalproduct') modalProduct;`
3. Call component method on the reference.

   `this.modalProduct.methodName();`